# Cannot edit a comment in Review UI

Tags: bug, status-declined, comments, review, user-interface

1. Open a Review Item (checked for Close queue @ SO)
2. Add a comment to the post being reviewed
3. Edit the comment
   => "An error occurred during comment submission" immediately

UPDATE: Despite having identified the case with audits in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270353/174091, I still encounter this sometimes in normal reviews. The cause is the same: real comment fns are being replaced by fakes. In particular, I see this happening when I browse back to the review that I've just voted on.

Comment: I can only enter the close queue again in 12 hours. I'll make a packet dump then.

Comment: Can't repro in SO LQP queue. (Manual comment, not delete reason auto-comment.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've (hopefully) [fixed the bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286682/3) when it occurs during non-audit situations.

As for audits, I think this was status-declined due to effort vs reward with how much work we wanted to put into making audits indistinguishable from real posts.

However, the current implementation is confusing, with its

> An error occurred during comment submission

message, so next build will have that text change to

> This is an audit

That should give the reviewer enough information to continue on and choose the correct path to pass the audit.

Comment: Isn't "This is an audit" defeating the purpose of audits?

Comment: Not really, it means you're actually trying to engage with the poster and not just "robo-reviewing", which is what audits are meant to curtail.

Comment: I.e. the act of adding a comment shows you're paying attention to the review and not just clicking an action as fast as you can.

Answer (score 4):

I've reproduced this - this time, it happened during comment *addition*.

Sniffer showed that *no* network requests are being made.
Debugging JS showed that the culprit is these lines in [`review.en.js`](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/review.en.js?v=4c2a1a000e09) (auto-prettified):

```
var t = !0,
n = function (e, t) {
    StackExchange.helpers.enableSubmitButton(e),
    StackExchange.helpers.showErrorMessage(t, 'An error occurred during comment submission')
};
StackExchange.comments.extendPostUi($.extend({
    'submitNewComment': function () {
        n(this.jDiv.find('form[id^="add-comment-"]'), this.jDiv)
    }
}, e), t),
```

This code overrides `submitNewComment` (and `submitEdit` just after the shown fragment) from [`full.en.js`](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=d51f0666beca) and, as you can see, the function indeed shows an error without POSTing anything.

Comment: I seem to have figured this out... but let's see what a developer has to say to... ahem... this.

Comment: Still happens, more frequently in the last two weeks.  I posted [this bug report](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23007/posting-comments-from-review-queues-has-become-error-prone) in Math.SE (adding Comments has become increasingly error prone) for a review that was not an audit (and a comment that successfully posted to the same Question outside the Review Queue).

Comment: @hardmath I wonder if it's another layer of Review Audits' disguise - a "false positive" this time. In http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270353/174091, I taunted the developers for "sloppy work"... _Looks like this was a BIG mistake._

Comment: I've now gone several days without seeing these errors while submitting new Comments, omitting of course the "legitimate" errors for review audits.  I think I got a couple of balky Comment edit submissions from review during this period, but not show stoppers.  So likely some fix in the system software has occurred in the last ten days or so.  Any evidence of a fix from your point of view?

Answer (score 3):

Figured this out. This happens if the review **is actually a review audit.** (BUSTED! - Guys, sloppy work! :) )

The functions that control the comments are then replaced by fakes (see the [previous answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270351/174091) for details).

I dunno how I managed to only run into this at *editing* stage. Maybe the overriding code was slow to load/execute, and I managed to submit a comment before it applied.

**Still, I maintain this is a bug.** The fact it's an audit is no reason to prevent me from doing any actions that are still valid:<sup>1</sup>

- if it's a real post, comments should work as usual
- if it isn't a real post, comments can still be faked to work. This can be detected by network activity or (if that is faked, too) submitting then reloading the page, but since an audit can be detected by simply pressing the question link anyway, this isn't much of a problem

  - given the scarcity of fake-post audits (I only ever saw those in suggested edits), there's little call for addressing the last case

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>even less so disguise it as a bug. I'd even go to say: *"The disguise was so perfect [it became an actual bug](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GoneHorriblyRight)!"*</sub>