# Annoying comment bug in review queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, review

The below bug doesn't *always* happen, but does *most of the time*.

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Go to any review queue
- Post a comment
- Edit the comment
- Click <kbd>Save Edits</kbd>

**Result:**

[image: Annoying Bug]

Obviously the red box above is the annoying bug...  **:-)**

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with your internet connection?

Comment: @Gothdo: Nah! 50Mbps SDSL here!  Why? Have you tried and you cannot reproduce it?

Comment: [Reported before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270236/cannot-edit-a-comment-in-review-ui) and declined with no reason, not voting to close this one so that it gets another chance.

Comment: Works here on Windows 10, Chrome 53.0.2785.143 (3 Mpbs internet, 80ms latency).

Comment: Hmm. Doesn't seem to affect me.

Comment: This affects me on Chrome 54.0.2840.71 on Windows 10 with a solid >10Mbps connection.

Comment: **Voted [the other one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286665/annoying-comment-bug-in-review-queue) as a dupe from this one as this is status-completed and the other one is status-declined**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alright, this bug manifested when navigating back (via browser back/forward buttons) to a review you had commented on, from a review audit.

Comment event handlers were being overwritten by audit-specific handlers, but when navigating to a real review from an audit, the non-audit handlers weren't being restored.

A fix will go out in the next build.

Comment: Thanks, but why was this exact same bug [declined before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270236/cannot-edit-a-comment-in-review-ui)? The developer who rejected it ignored my comment to explain, and same with my flag which is [pending for over 10 months](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPDDP.png). (!)

Comment: I've [answered there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286709/3), too, and handled the flag - thank you!